# Assigning a function for focusOutEvent to a widget

Tags: c++, qt

I want to do specific things after focus is lost on lineedit1. Here is the code piece from the application:

```
QFocusEvent* focuslost = new QFocusEvent(QEvent::FocusOut);
void lineedit1::focusOutEvent(focuslost) {
  //do something
}
```

but it gives me compiler error:

> > error: name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name

What can I do to implement such a function?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just override a method on an instance of an object, you need to create a new class that inherits from `QLineEdit` and overrides the method `focusOutEvent`:

**mylineedit.h**

```
class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
protected:
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent * e) override;
}
```

**mylineedit.cpp**

```
void MyLineEdit::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent * e)
{
    // your code here

    QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(e);
}
```

Then declare `lineedit1` as `MyLineEdit* lineedit1`